# Bounds of third integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

For integrals:

$\iiint_D x^{2}yz \, \mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz$, where $D$ is limited by surfaces: $x = 2, y=x^2, z=0, x+y=z$.

$\iiint_D xz \, \mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz$, where $D$ is limited by surfaces: $y = x^2, y=1, z=0, x+y=z$.

What would the limits be?

I totally don't know how to look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
$$I_1=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{-x}^{x^2}\int_{0}^{x+y}x^2 yz\,dz\,dy\,dx$$

[image]
$$I_2=\int_{-1}^{0}\int_{-x}^{1}\int_{0}^{x+y}xz\,dz\,dy\,dx+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x^2}^{1}\int_{0}^{x+y} xz\,dz\,dy\,dx$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I only don't understand why $y =-x$. How it works? I know this is from $x+y=z$ but what is the rule?

Comment: $$z=0 \quad, z=x+y\implies x+y=0$$

Comment: Ok... That was stupid question. Thank you again.